Pandas without sqlite3
There is a transitive dependency of Pandas on sqlite3 via SqlAlchemy. Hence, if you don't have sqlite3 installed on Linux or Windows, Pandas won't run. It will show this error.

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘_sqlite3’

Since I don't need SQLite3 in my project, want to run / use Pandas without SQLite3 ?

Sqlite3 comes with standard python, why do you uninstall it?

How are you using Pandas without having Python installed? And if you have Python installed, how do you not have sqlite3? Surely you catch my drift.

To bypass sqlite3 if you don't need it with Pandas, write below code in a file named _sqlite3.py and save it in site-packages folder of your virtual environment or python installation.
# _sqlite3.py

version = "3.1"
sqlite_version = "3.1"

class Row:
    pass

def register_adapter(a,b):
    pass

def register_converter(a,b):
    pass

class Connection():
    pass


Tested on Arch Linux and Python 3.8
Note: This might work not just Pandas but for other libraries as well where Sqlite3 is a dependency and you don't have it installed.

Again, sqlite3 is part of Python. This makes no sense.
